# Interpolation between $L_p$ and $B^s_{q,q}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, function-spaces, interpolation-spaces

I am looking for a reference or a direct argument that shows the real interpolation space between $L_p$ and $B^s_{q,q}$ is $B^\alpha_{r,r}$, with the usual conditions on the indices. This result is stated in many places, and they refer to, e.g., a paper of DeVore and Popov on interpolation of Besov spaces, but this paper is concerned with only interpolation between two Besov spaces. When I try to replace one of the Besov spaces by an $L_p$ space, I run into the problem of writing $L_p$ as an $\ell_q^s(L_p)$-type space. I might be missing some simple argument. I would really appreciate if you give me some pointer.

**Update**: Below we have a couple of good answers. Thank you! However, I was hoping to see a more direct proof that does not go through Triebel-Lizorkin spaces. An approximation theory approach would be ideal for me. My real purpose is to have a similar interpolation result for certain approximation spaces, and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces do not seem to have analogues in approximation setting. If I have to, I will try to translate the proof through Triebel-Lizrokin into an approximation setting, but I wanted to check if a standard trick already exists in the literature. I apologize for not making it clear the first time.

Comment: I suspect that this can be derived using the reiteration theorem for interpolation.

Comment: @Dunham: Reiteration approach seems to require writing $L_p$ as an interpolation space between Besov spaces, which I think is not possible (By interpolation you cannot get out of the Besov scale).

Comment: I haven't checked this carefully, but perhaps one could simply use the inclusions $B^0_{p,1} \subset L_p \subset B^0_{p,\infty}$ together with Besov space interpolation?

Comment: @TerryTao: I think in order for $[B^0_{p,t},B^s_{q,q}]_{\theta,r}=B^\alpha_{r,r}$ to happen we must have $t=p$.

Comment: I mean, we will have $[B^0_{p,1},B^s_{q,q}]_{\theta,r}\subset[L_{p},B^s_{q,q}]_{\theta,r}\subset[B^{0}_{p,\infty},B^s_{q,q}]_{\theta,r}$ but (from what I understand) the spaces on the two sides are not Besov spaces.

Comment: I don't believe t=p is necessary.  Bergh and Lofstrom (for instance) should have details; I don't have access to it here, but the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#Interpolation_of_Sobolev_and_Besov_spaces asserts that the required interpolation result is in Theorem 6.4.5 of that text.

Comment: @TerryTao: Thanks for looking this up. Actually I have the book and the theorem is identical to what is on Wikipedia. If you look at the conditions on the indices, they require $t=p$ because we already fixed the indices of other two spaces. The theorem in Bergh and Lofstrom follows from another earlier theorem on interpolation between Banach valued sequence spaces, and if the indices are general one would get Besov spaces (with 4 indices) based on Lorentz spaces $L_{p,q}$.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  (I had misread the Wikipedia entry.)  In that case, one probably has no choice but to use some Calderon-Zygmund theory (as is for instance implicit in the statement that $L^p = F^0_{p2}$) as otherwise one doesn't seem to be able to handle all the varying indices simultaneously.

Comment: @TerryTao: It seems so, and it seems not as complicated as I initially thought. But probably it would be a nonstandard application of CZ theory (The spaces I have are approximation spaces related to multiresolution analysis defined by piecewise polynomials on triangulations). Thank you for your input!

Comment: We know the equivalence between interpolation spaces and approximation spaces, so you could try to directly show the equivalence between the approximation space norms and Besov norms for band-limited approximation. However, it seems that there are easier approaches to this problem.

Comment: @Dunham: That is how DeVore and Popov proved their Besov space interpolation results. I think the idea goes back to Nikolsky's school. What do you have in mind as easier approaches?

Comment: @TerryTao: What happens for $0<p\leq1$? Is there a Littlewood-Paley theory in this case?

Comment: Generally the situation with $p \leq 1$ is quite pathological, particularly the non-convex, non-locally integrable case $p<1$.  Things are better if one uses Hardy spaces instead of Lebesgue spaces though.

Answer (score 2):

See Equation (8.33) of Triebel, Spaces of distributions of Besov type on Euclidean n-space. Duality, interpolation, 1973. (MR0348483)

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 8 on page 53 in [these lecture notes](http://www.rni.helsinki.fi/~msa/teaching/function_spaces/fsp08_lectures.pdf) gives a number of interpolation results for Besov and Triebel spaces.
The results are partially proven, and a citation is given for the rest (Triebel's book *Interpolation theory, function spaces, differential operators*).
Since $L^p=F^0_{p2}$ and $B^s_{qq}=F^s_{qq}$, the first equality of part (b) is what you need.

Comment: These are all good answers, but I was hoping to see a more direct proof that does not go through the Triebel-Lizorkin spaces, for instance, by approximation theory.

Comment: Has there been any update on this question? I am interested in the real interpolation between $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $W^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, again without using the Triebel-Lizorkin spaces. Thanks!

Comment: @Gio67 I recommend asking a separate new question and linking to this one.

Comment: I think that the book by Besov, Il'in, and Nikol'ski, "Integral representations of functions and imbedding theorems." Vol. II. has what I want. They deal with anisotropic Besov and Sobolev spaces and allow the functions and their derivatives to belong to different $L^p$ spaces. It's just excruciating to read.